# How to add tracking number to ShipOrderInterface programmatically

Tags: magento2, shipping, programmatically, shipment-tracking

How can I passed the tracking number to the Model `\Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface`. The method is working with a empty array.

this is the code I've made for testing, but it's not working:

```
<?php
namespace Maru3l\SyncOrchestra\Cron;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface;

class SyncOrder extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $sourceItemInterface;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $shipOrderInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ShipOrderInterface $shipOrderInterface
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->shipOrderInterface = $shipOrderInterface;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

/**
   * Request quantity from Orchestra and update quantity in Source
   *
   * @return void
   */

    public function execute()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(
                'status',
                'processing',
                'eq'
            )
            ->create();

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
            try {
                $this->shipOrderInterface->execute(
                    $order->getEntityId(),
                    array(),
                    true,
                    false,
                    null,
                    array(
                        array(
                                "track_number" => "test-tracking",
                                "carrier_code" => "canadapost",
                                "title" => "Poste Canada"
                        )
                    ),
                    array(),
                    null
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm doing a little plugin who sync the database of a custom inventory system with magento.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can create a tracking element with `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory` like this:

```
$track = $this->trackFactory->create();
$track->setCarrierCode("canadapost");
$track->setTitle("Poste Canada");
$track->setDescription("Poste Canada");
$track->setTrackNumber("test-tracking-number-1234");
```

and pass it to the array.